# My account reps from yesterday is counted today

Tags: support, reputation

My account shows 95 reps today, but 85 of those are from yesterday. There was a similar bug a while back.

It doesn't bother me, but I thought I'd report it.

Answer (score 2):

So, the way the columns in the profile popup that shows when you hover over your name at the top of the page is implemented is that we just have a column that stores and increases the number throughout the day.  Then, at exactly 0:00 UTC, we have a job that sets everyone's daily value to 0, and the increasing begins again.

Unfortunately, last night, there were some, um, [issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125729/140548), and the servers were very unhappy with us.  This prevented the column from being reset to 0.

This will naturally be corrected at the UTC rollover tonight.  We are leaving it as is for today as this isn't very high priority for the work to fix it.